# How to insert touch events into html5 circular slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, round-slider, circular-slider

The code works perfectly using mouse events but when switch to touch event or vmouse event, it stopped working.

Here's the link for the mouse event code [https://jsfiddle.net/tk2zd47e/2/ ]

I've tried **`vmousemove/vmouseup/vmousedown`**, **`touchstart/touchend/touchmove`** and **`e.preventDefault()`**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you are trying to create your own circular slider, which is pretty good.

Alternatively you can use the jQuery [**roundSlider**](http://roundsliderui.com/) plugin, which is more suitable for your requirement. It supports in **Desktop**, **Mobile** and **Touch** devices also.

This is very flexible and very easy to customize so that you can make any [custom appearance](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html#different-theming-and-appearances) as per your wish.

Here i make an demo exactly same as your requirement: [**`jsFiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/LpuLe9tr/9/)

For more details check the [demos](http://roundsliderui.com/demos.html) and [documentation](http://roundsliderui.com/document.html) page.

**Screenshot of the Output:**

[image: round slider color picker - jquery plugin]

Comment: Is it possible to use 2 different events? E.g. The circle be using change event while the numbers in drag event.

Comment: Yes, you can use both change and drag event.. Are you expecting like this ?  http://jsfiddle.net/soundar24/LpuLe9tr/13/

Comment: Oh yes, that's what I am expecting. I should have realised that I should put a comma right after every event.